# Is there a term for words differing in stress (only)?

Tags: terminology, stress, lexicography

That is words that is pronunced equally *except* the stress pattern differs. For example "digest /daɪˈdʒɛst/" (verb) and "digest /ˈdaɪdʒɛst/" (noun). Or even the case where the stress are of different kinds "anden /¹andɛn/" (swedish: the duck) and "anden /²andɛn/" (swedish: the spirit)

All the examples I can think of actually spells the same, but that is not a requirement (if you could find an example that doesn't). I don't know if there's any example where they are spelled differently.

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question. However, although the words *'absent* and *ab'sent* may be spelled the same, they have different phonemes in (in other words they aren't pronounced the same way apart from their different stresses). In particular, the verb has an /e/ in the final syllable, whereas the adjective and preposition both have a schwa, /ə/.

Comment: @Araucaria-him damn schwas, I think I found a better example (in the list of such words "digest" is noted to use the same phonemes)

Comment: The Swedish example is a case of minimal pairs distinguished by _tone_. I don’t actually know if there is a term for those specifically, but they are cross-linguistically **much** more common than minimal pairs distinguished by stress (just consider largely monosyllabic and highly tonal Asian languages that will often have such minimal pairs for almost every syllable in the language).

Comment: Those are called **homographs**; spelled the same way, pronounced differently. [I think you mean the tonic accent is different.] If the tonic accent is different, the pronunciation changes. graduate [verb] and the person who gets the degree, noun.

Comment: *Absent* and *absent* don't differ phonemically; there's only a *phonetic* difference caused by the unaccented vowel in *absent* reducing to schwa (and possibly additionally [ən] reducing to [n̩]), which is quite regular. If a phonemic transcription writes them differently it is at best sloppy.

Comment: @Lambie *Tonic* and accent are normally reserved for IP level analysis, not words.

Comment: @Lambie The examples given in the question happen to be homographs, but stress-based minimal pairs need not be homographs (e.g., Spanish _tomo_ ‘I take’ vs _tomó_ ‘s/he took’), and homographs also include many pairs that aren’t stress-based (e.g., _sow_ /soʊ/ ‘plant seeds’ vs _sow_ /saʊ/ ‘female pig’).

Comment: I think “stress minimal pair” (minimal pair distinguished by stress for more precision) is the obvious name for this.

Comment: https://dle.rae.es/hom%C3%B3grafo 1. adj. Ling. Dicho de una palabra: Que tiene la misma grafía que otra. **Vino 'bebida' y vino 'forma del verbo venir' son términos homógrafos.** [wine the drink and came from the verb venir (come) are homographs). stress patterns and minimal pairs are not the same thing.

Comment: @Lambie Perhaps I was an bit unclear in my question, but it's no requirement that they are spelled the same. A requirement was that the words were pronunced the same except for the stress pattern. Correct me if I'm wrong, but two words spelled differently aren't homographs, and two words pronounced differently may still be homographs.d

Answer (score 2):

The general term for two distinct words differing exclusively in terms of a single property is "minimal pair". There is no special technical term for "differing only in stress" (or nasality, or voicing), so we would construct a phrase like "stress minimal pair", "voicing minimal pair" and so on.

However, the entire basis for defining minimal pairs is radically different in the case of stress, as opposed to other properties. If we have [pat] versus [bat] or [pad] versus [pat], where "[pat]" is the phonetic output, we have minimal pairs for voicing because in the phonetic output there is exactly one segment in {[pat, bat]} which differentiates the two words. That is what it means to be "minimal". If instead we have {[pat, bɔt]}, the pair is non-minimal, even if under analysis it turns out that [ɔ] always derives from /a/ after a voiced obstruent. Instead, we have a co-dependency, or co-variation.

In [daɪˈdʒɛst] versus [ˈdaɪdʒɛst] you have co-variation where in the verb form, σ1 is unstressed and σ2 is stressed but in the noun σ1 is stressed and σ2 is unstressed (following your analysis / transcriptions – usually, the noun form is transcribed [ˈdaɪˌdʒɛst], with secondary stress on the second syllable, compared to [ˈbɪgɨst]). In that case, the difference is not minimal, there is co-variation.

Theoretically, for English, you would be looking for a pair of words where primary stress is on a particular syllable and the other syllables differ in having secondary stress versus no stress. Pairs like "latex" and "latest" are in that ballpark, except that there are numerous other differences, i.e. this is not *minimal*, it just illustrates that "1-2" and "1-0" are contrastive stress patterns. In English, vowel reduction messes up the quest for a true stress minimal pair between secondary stress vs. no stress. There simply are no stress minimal pairs, given that "minimal pair" is a way of classifying phonetic outputs.

Your invocation of spelling introduces some uncertainty as to what you are really asking, since it suggests a more specific interest in orthographic defects, where one cannot completely predict the pronunciation of words from their spelling (English has lots of that). Russian exemplifies this problem, that the spelling system does not tell you where the stress of a word is even though it is contrastive. Many languages have such orthographic defects for various properties, and stress differences are particularly omitted from spelling practices (e.g. Italian ancora 'anchor' vs 'more').

Comment: "The general term for two distinct words differing exclusively in terms of a single property is "minimal pair"."  That is not true. They can have different tonic accents and be the same minimal pairs in terms of phones. They can be heteronyms or homophones.

Comment: @Lambie Who's army?

Comment: @Araucaria-him A general term has nothing to do with generals. Are you making a joke?

Comment: @Lambie I meant on whose authority do those claims stand?

Comment: @Araucaria-him What claim**s**? Do you agree with the OP's assertion I quoted above? I certainly do not.

Comment: First of all my question wasn't intended to not put any requirements on spelling. The note about spelling was just that I don't know any example where two such words are actually spelled differently. But looking after minimal pairs I've found some examples here: https://sv.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lista_%C3%B6ver_svenska_ordaccentsskilda_minimala_par (fx almen vs allmän, B:na vs bena, brevvän vs breven) also noting that these doesn't suffer from the covariation as the stress is on the same syllable, but the stress if of different kinds.

Comment: As for english I'm not sure, but isn't it just the placement of the primary stress that is a phoneme? Or is there an example where pronunciation matches except that secondary stressed is placed differently? Also is covariation that big deal anyway? Two phonemes could differ in more than one way without there's a phoneme differing in only one way. For example in danish there's a voiceless alveolar fricative and a voiced alveolar approximant (differing in two aspect, but theres is no voiced alveololar fricative and no voiceless alveolar approximant which would differ only in one aspect)

Comment: @Lambie Are you claiming that a tone is not a single property?

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet No, I am not. I am saying that this: "The general term for two distinct words differing exclusively in terms of a single property is "minimal pair".  is not true." A minimal pair is when there are two words with a different phoneme in the same position: bat, bit//ship//sheep, for example.

Comment: @Lambie That’s quite simply not true. Minimal pairs are determined by _properties_ (or ‘phonological elements’ as Wikipedia calls it), not just phonemes. So yes, tones can indeed form minimal pairs. Mandarin _mā/mà_ form a minimal pair just as much as _mā/bā_ do, or indeed as Finnish _tuli/tuuli_ do. In all cases, the distinguishing factor is a single property: tone contour, oral vs nasal airflow (concomitantly audible vs inaudible release), vowel length. One of these unambiguously maps to two separate phonemes, one arguably does so, and one does not, but that’s incidental.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Call them phonemes (written) or phones (spoken), That sentence I quoted is not true. Yes, bat and fat differ only by a minimal pair. No point in quoting Chinese at me though of course that example is always the one example always quoted to non-Chinese speakers. Even I quoted that example in this forum at some point. Fyi, I was not covering all languages and certainly not tones. So, your question is like: "Why did you kill your wife" instead of "Did you kill your wife".

Comment: @Lambie “phonemes (written) or phones (spoken)” – what? No. Phonemes and phones are both concepts that describe spoken language; written language has neither. And the definition of what constitutes a minimal pair does not depend on language. It’s the same for English as for any other language. The only thing that differs is what properties a language possesses that can be used to create minimal pairs.

Comment: [con't] Certainly not tone "languages".  Imagine if I said to you: And I betcha in click languages, the same word with or without a click would be a minimal pair too. Why not mention Khoekhoegowab: Fredericks_PHD_2013.pdf Much more exotic.